# How to store array of values in application.properties file and fetch it to display them in a thyme leaf template

Tags: spring-boot, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, thymeleaf, properties-file

I wanted to store a list of blood groups in the application properties file so that it can be fetched and displayed in a dropdown list while the user is asked to pick a blood group. I'm using thyme leaf template engine. I wanted to use this to avoid hard coding as much as possible(for learning experience). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. In application.properties file, define one property bloodGroups

> bloodGroups=A+,B+,AB+

2. In java class(may be controller) bind this property

> ```
> @Value("${bloodGroups}")
> private String[] bloodGroups;
> ```

3. In your controller class set this as model attribute

> model.addAttribute("bloodGroups", bloodGroups);

4. Access in thmeleaf

> ```
> <select required="true" name="bloodGroup" id="bloodGroup">
>                               <option th:selected/>
>                               <option th:each="bloodGroup: ${bloodGroups}" th:value="${bloodGroup}" th:text="${bloodGroup}"></option>
>                           </select>
> ```

Comment: @michael Is this the answer for you question?

Comment: When I tried to use Value annotation at controller it is saying "The annotation @Value is disallowed for this location". How can I avoid that?

Comment: You are getting compilation or while starting the server? and make sure you are using Springframework @Value annotation.

Comment: And Make @Value should be inside the class and outside the method not inside the method, it should be at class level.

Comment: When I compile it is showing "The annotation @Value is disallowed for this location. The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Value". I placed the value annotation inside the class itself.

Comment: Can you please share your part of your code.